# Efficiency of diesel generator running a geothermal heat pump

Tags: hvac, generator

I'm looking at a 40KW (continuous) Kubota Diesel generator for whole house backup in a sustained power outage of a week or two.

Everything in my house is electric, including the heat, and the house is large. The heat is an efficient geothermal pump though, so I'm wondering if feeding this off the generator is more efficient than a secondary boiler. There's no natural gas available or propane on site.

By my calculations, running at half load:
20KW consumes 1.7GPH (per Kubota), $3/gallon = 25c/KWh (vs 12c/KWh electric)

1 gallon diesel = 137,452 Btu ~= 40KWH. 
So I burn 3.4 gallons of diesel / gallon of diesel energy ~= 30% efficient

However, the heating [COP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance) of the Waterfurnace 5 ton heat pump is 4.5.

The way I understand this is *approximately* I'll get back 0.3 * 4.5 of energy for a total efficiency of 135%. I appreciate there are other small losses in the system, both manufacturers are probably exaggerating a little etc but still it seems better than running a diesel boiler (~90% efficient?) to heat the house.

Is my reasoning correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Something is off because you can't have more than 100% efficiency.  I don't totally understand what you're doing here, but multiplying that `0.3 * 4.5` can't be right.  Also, not sure what COP is.

Comment: @JPhi1618 You can't have more than 100% efficiency if you don't know what COP is.

Comment: Apparently you can have snark if you do, though. @JPhi1618, heat pumps aren't described by total efficiency, but another standard that compares work and heat exchange. Link added to question.

Comment: Ok, well that will be the thing that I learned today.  Interesting.

Comment: Even if the calculation is not right, the next question would be what percentage of the time you’ll be running this way, and how many years (or decades) it would take to pay back the cost of a complete backup heating system.

Comment: An ideal electric resistance water heater is 100 % efficient, in that all the electric energy is captured by the water in the heater.  A good quality heat pump water heater can do better than that and so can have "efficiency" greater than 100 % if one defines efficiency as a ratio of energy added to the water divided by the electric energy required to do this. Using a heat pump it is possible to TRANSFER from the environment a given quantity of heat into water with an expenditure of electric energy which is LESS than the quantity of heat transferred. The rub is this pump is expensive.

Comment: well in all fairness, thermodynamics are *weird*.  Latent heat... mass doesn't store heat... heat pumps *themselves* are a hat trick, and then we add *nuclear energy* into the mix, as we are in this case...

Comment: @JPhi1618, you can get more than 100% efficiency with a heatpump .... you are not generating the heat .... you are only moving heat from one place to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your math. Ground sources are quite useful for achieving reasonable heat pump efficiency year-round.

*Also*, it's possible to scavenge some of the 70% loss at the generator by collecting radiator or exhaust heat.  This is called **cogeneration** and [Honda has offered this system](http://world.honda.com/power/cogenerator/) for awhile.

Comment: Honda utilizes waste heat from a spark ignition generator, but not from a compression ignition generator. Spark ignition engine have a lot more waste heat than compression ignition engines so it is worth the expense of recapturing the energy that would just go out the exhaust, but it is not worth it for compression ignition engines which have a much higher compression (and expansion) ratio. The fact that diesels are much more efficient than gasoline engines means there is  much less energy in the exhaust.

Comment: Intriguing idea. The [generator in question](https://www.centralmainediesel.com/order/Kubota-40-kW-Diesel-Generator.asp?page=KB4500) is liquid cooled with a radiator and fan, so in theory one could just move the radiator into the house .... 

In practice, I suspect it's painful with setback requirements, insulation, burying them underground etc ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a good deal, but a natural gas unit will be by cheaper to run. 
In your case you can legally use oil #2 (aka off-road diesel aka heating oil) that is the same as diesel instead of road-diesel to avoid the road taxes.

Comment: Sadly, running natural gas to the property isn't feasible, or I'd definitely use that. I've read mixed reports on using #2 oil - apparently the make up varies quite a bit and it invalidates the warranty. Off road diesel should be fine though (it's a farm). Fortunately the power doesn't go out for long periods of time too often.

Comment: So use red-diesel and it'll be fine (just don't put it in your truck).

Comment: Do not put red diesel in a highway vehicle.  The dye is very potent and will take about 10 fill-ups to purge the dye...